# How to convert a list of variable names into a list of formal symbols?

Tags: string-manipulation, symbols

I have a lists of variable names that include greek letters.

```
names = {"a", "b", "μ", "Σ"}
```

I would like to construct a lists of formal symbols from these such the above list will return

```
{\[FormalA], \[FormalB], \[FormalMu], \[FormalCapitalSigma]}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I have tried mapping `Symbol` with no luck.

```
Symbol["$" <> #] & /@ names
```

> ```
> {$a, $b, $μ, $Σ]}
> ```

How do I get a list of formal symbols from a list of variable names.

Answer (score 4):

The ploddingly straightforward method:

```
SetAttributes[formalize, Listable];
formalize[s_String] /; StringLength[s] == 1 := 
          Module[{la = Alphabet[], ga = Alphabet["Greek"]},
                 Which[MemberQ[la, s], FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[s] + 63391],
                       MemberQ[ToUpperCase[la], s], 
                       FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[s] + 63449], 
                       MemberQ[ga, ToLowerCase[s]], 
                       FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[s] + 62627]]]
```

Comment: Your character manipulations put me on a different tract with some version 10 functions that results. Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Solution inspired by @JM's answer which resulted in finding `CharacterName`.  With this the `FullForm` of the formal symbols can be obtained as strings and `Symbol` used to create the symbols.

```
ClearAll[formalSymbol];
formalSymbol[s_String] /; StringLength[s] == 1 :=
 Which[

  (* English characters *)
  StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ Alphabet[Language -> "English"], IgnoreCase -> True]@s,
  Symbol@StringJoin[{"\\", "[Formal", If[UpperCaseQ@s, "Capital", ""],ToUpperCase@s, "]"}],

  (* Greek characters *)
  StringContainsQ[Alternatives @@ Alphabet[Language -> "Greek"], IgnoreCase -> True]@s,
  Symbol@StringJoin[{"\\", "[Formal", CharacterName@s, "]"}],

  True,
  Message[Symbol::symname, s]
  ]
```

Then

```
formalSymbol /@ {"a", "A", "σ", "Σ"}
```

> ```
> {\[FormalA], \[FormalCapitalA], \[FormalSigma], \[FormalCapitalSigma]}
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]