# How to convert a list of indexed variable names to a list of formal symbols?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, built-in-symbols

I have the following list of indexed variable names:

```
list = {x1,x2,x3,x4};
```

I would like to build a list of formal symbols from the above list, i.e.

```
{\[Formax1], \[Formax2], \[Formalx3], \[Formalx4]}
```

I've tried mapping `Symbol` to the names in the list, but it doesn't work. ㋡

Comment: See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158950).

Comment: The input `{\[Formax1],\[Formax2],\[Formalx3],\[Formalx4]}` gives a syntax error (V12.3).

Comment: Your variable names are already symbols. You can see this by looking the full form of an element. e.g.: list[[1]] //FullForm

Comment: Does `Symbol /@ StringReplace[ToString /@ list, "x" -> "\[FormalX]"]` give you what you want?

Comment: Some more context would be helpful. \\[Formalx4] is not a named character. There are named characters that have "Formal" in their name, but you can't just make up new characters on the fly like this. What use do you need these "formal" characters for?

Comment: Are you trying to get your symbols to display with the under-dot?

Comment: Hi @leric! You are correct in what you point out. I ask this because I have a function that generates lists of indexed symbols for me and I wanted to avoid conflicts in case I pre-assign values for those symbols at some point (I think I avoid it by being careful and using ClearAll[symbols]). So I thought about the possibility of the formal symbol (symbols with the under-dot), but I see that it doesn't work.

Comment: @LouisB, your suggestion works very well, can those symbols be protected as in the case of any formal symbol with a single character? :)

Comment: @user293787 thanks for sharing that nice discussion on formal symbols. :)

Comment: @LouisB please post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks for the comment, but what I need is to get symbols with the under-dot. :)

Comment: If you're worried about conflicts, an easier route might be to use Unique. You can simultaneously get the Protected attributed added. E.g. `Unique[x1, {Protected}]` will generate a symbol like `x$8658` and it will have the Protected attribute. You can even use Unique on a list of symbols. E.g. given your `list` above, you could do `Unique[list,{Protected}]` and get `{x1$21285, x2$21285, x3$21285, x4$21285}`. It'll even handle the situation where `list` has duplicates.

Comment: Just a caution. If you're working with the output of a function that generates symbols, and you already have defintions for some of those symbols, then none of these suggestions will actually work for you. Before you even try to operate on the list of symbols, the evaluator will already have expanded them using their OwnValues. Is this function one you wrote yourself? If so, you can change it to return something less volatile. If not, you may have to open a new Context, or do some fancy scoping.

Comment: @lericr Thank you for clarifying these details for me, it works very well. If you can add this comment as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to be very careful--you might not be able to get what you want. You mentioned that you're getting a list of symbols from a function. Let's mimic that:

```
symbolGenerator[] := {x1, x2, x3, x4};
symbolGenerator[]
(* returns {x1, x2, x3, x4} *)
```

Okay, let's say you wanted to use Unique on these so that you avoid name collisions. Well, it should work fine if none of the symbols were defined.

```
Unique[symbolGenerator[]]
(* {x1$7526, x2$7526, x3$7526, x4$7526} *)
```

But let's try again in a situation where there's actually a name collision:

```
ClearAll[x1, x2, x3, x4, symbolGenerator];
symbolGenerator[] := {x1, x2, x3, x4};
x3 = 17;
Unique[symbolGenerator[]]
```

Now we get a message saying `"17 is not a symbol or a valid symbol name"`.

If you implemented `symbolGenerator`, then you could return strings instead of symbols; you could wrap the output in Hold or maybe Unevaluated; you could add a context directly to the symbols; or you could use Unique to start with. For example:

```
symbolGenerator[] := Unique[{"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"}]
(* or *)
symbolGenerator[] := Symbol[StringJoin["special`", #]] & /@ {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"}
```

If you didn't implement `symbolGenerator`, then we'd probably need to know more about that function before making concrete suggestions.