# Can a pure function be constructed whose argument list is a matrix?

Tags: function-construction, pure-function

Can a pure function be constructed whose argument list is a matrix?

Using `Function`, I know it's not possible, but I'd like to get something like:

```
Function[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, {-2 y1 y2, 8 x1 x2 - 2 x2 y1 - 2 x1 y2}]
```

In general, I would like to obtain a pure function whose argument has the alternatives of being a vector or a matrix. Something like this:

```
MyFunction[vector | matrix, vectorfunction]:=
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way to specify the function, but this works:

```
Function[{-2 #[[1, 2]] #[[2, 2]], 8 #[[1, 1]] #[[2, 1]] - 2 #[[2, 1]] #[[1, 2]] - 2 #[[1, 1]] #[[2, 2]]}]
```

I'm not sure how to answer the matrix-or-vector question without more information.

Comment: Do you like collaborations? :)

Comment: Possibly. What’s up?

Comment: Do you remember when I asked about an unprotected symbol generator? That question is related to this post. I would like to find collaboration to finish a function that is very useful in normal forms theory.

Comment: Using `Function` is the most appropriate way, not using formal symbols, as I asked on that occasion.

Comment: Generalizing your answer, the function I'm working on remains without possible issues, but it would be nice to collaborate.

Comment: I don’t remember, but I can try to help.

Comment: The previous post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272191/how-to-convert-a-list-of-indexed-variable-names-to-a-list-of-formal-symbols

Comment: @E.Chan-López If you want to be able to do something different for matrices and vectors, I think the operator form of `Replace` is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use `Replace` if you want to be able to use patterns?

```
fun = Replace[
  {
   {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}?MatrixQ :> {-2 y1 y2, 
     8 x1 x2 - 2 x2 y1 - 2 x1 y2},
   {x1_, y1_}?VectorQ :> x1 + y1 (*or whatever *)
   }
];
fun @ {a, b}
fun @ {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}
```

Comment: Is the `VectorQ` and `MatrixQ` required in that case ? Would the structure `fun[{x1_, y1_}] := x1; fun[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := x2` have the same behavior?

Comment: @userrandrand It is if you want to make sure it does what you want. The pattern `{x1_, y1_}` also matches a matrix with 2 rows `MatchQ[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}, {x1_, y1_}]`. You should always be careful with overlapping patterns like that. If you know exactly what kinds of input you can expect, you can usually do without these tests, but otherwise its best to be defensive.

Comment: Nice, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

One could convert the matrix to an association with string valued keys indicating matrix positions and use named slots.

For example:

```
(Slot["{1, 2}"]*Slot["{1, 1}"] &)@
KeyMap[ToString, Association@Most@ArrayRules@{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}]
```

Out:  `(* x1 y1 *)`

That is rather lengthy to use. One could package that into auxiliary functions.

#### Auxiliary functions

The first list/matrix to association function:

```
listorule[list_] := KeyMap[ToString, Association@Most@ArrayRules@list]
```

The second function makes it a bit easier to write the `Slot` arguments. One can change the notation as explained in the next section.

```
ss[indices__] := Slot@ToString@List[indices]
```

The last function replaces `Function` or `&` to control the evaluation order and makes it convenient to compose `listtorule` on the right.

```
func[a_] := Function[Evaluate[a]]@*listorule;
```

**Note**: There might be cases where one does not want to use `Evaluate` on the entire expression in which case `func` above might evaluate too much  of the expression.

#### Example above rewritten

Reconsidering the example above, one can code the following function

```
h = ss[1, 1]*ss[2, 2] // func
```

Test:

```
h@{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}
```

Out:  `(* x1 y2 *)`

#### Possible modifications

The syntax could be simplified by adding an extra dictionary/association between a user defined notation and string of positions. For example, if the size of the matrix is smaller than 10 one could consider writing `ss@12*ss@11`. The reason for the restriction on matrices smaller than 10 is to avoid ambiguity in something like `ss@143`.

One might also consider maybe rewriting some of the steps above using `With` and using symbols we feel comfortable with which would skip the `Evaluate` part. That seems reasonable for a very long function but it is a bit tedious for a small function.